# Display tag using java

Tags: java, jstl, displaytag

How to sort the column using displaytag in java my code is as follows:

```
<display:column property="bulk" title="User Name" sortable="false"/>
<display:column   title="File Name" >
    <c:url value="../BulkHistoryDetails" var="url">
    <c:param name="ID" value="${row.bulk}"/>
    <c:param name="FileName" value="${row.filename}"/>
    </c:url>
    <a href=${url}>${row.filename}</a> 
   </display:column>
```

i want to sort filename column which is having values like 
PJ00xxxx Data for Usage 32013-02-18_04-50-47.xls
 and if click on filename it is going to other jsp. as it is already have hiperlink i am not able to use sorttabe=true as if i click on file name header it goes to another jsp not sorting .please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably post your entire display tag code starting with `<display:table name="fileList">`.

It sounds like you want the column heading to function as a sort button when you click on it and for the data within that column to function as hyperlinks. I don't see why this should be a problem. When you add the sortabler="true" attribute to the `"File Name"` column it turns the column heading into a hyperlink? Really? What does it link to?

If the column heading does somehow become a hyperlink then you can try a creating a link from the row column data using a [Table Decorator](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/tut_decorators.html) or the `href` attribute, both described here: [display tag docs](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/tut_links.html). I think either of these approaches results in a cleaner solution than what you have now.

Comment: What happens to the column heading when you use sortable="true" for that column? What does it link to?

Comment: when i add sortable="true" it link to my servlet which i mention in c:url

Comment: What id and filename parameters are passed? I'm assuming row is your row variable referencing some FileObject. What value is row.filename when you are not on a row?